# How to get a list of members, from our Facebook group with 85,000 members?

Tags: list, facebook, xpath, member, rpa

I need a list of alle our members from our Facebook group, 85,000 members.

I have tried Xpath and auto scool with Google Chrome, and Uipath RPA; But Chrome cant handle it.
What should i do?

Best regards Robert

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, you must use the api. not sure if there is an api for it though, because of data privacy - no app can access data of users if they did not specifically authorize your app.

Comment: what do you want to achieve anyway? maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Do you have tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `Send Hotkey` activity to send pgdn for scrolling down and then use `Data Scraping` in UiPath Studio.

[image: Robotic-Process-Automation-UiPath-Test-GetFacebookGroupMembers00001]

Example Code: https://github.com/akkapolk/Robotic-Process-Automation-UiPath-Test-GetFacebookGroupMembers00001